# Merge [entity-attribute-value] tag into [eav]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Someone created [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) 17 days ago. It currently has 10 questions in the tag.  [eav](/questions/tagged/eav) was created a year ago and has 234 questions. These tags apply to precisely the same thing. Should the new one be merged into the old one (or at least made a synonm)?

I don't have the requirements to suggest or vote for a synonym, but it seems like a good thing to clear up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've merged [eav](/questions/tagged/eav) into [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) and I also updated the tag wiki on [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) to contain a summary and a description based on the summary from [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) and the full wiki from [eav](/questions/tagged/eav).

Answer (score 5):

They should be merged, and made synonyms.

It seems more preferable to keep [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) as main site, and use [eav](/questions/tagged/eav) as synonym. In either way, the tags should be merged.

Comment: *Definitely* preferable to keep the tag that actually describes what it's about. I have no idea what `[eav]` is, but I know what an `[entity-attribute-value]` is.